# C++ code throws exception when referencing XSLT code with jqplots

Tags: c++, xslt, jqplot

**Summary**

I have a C++ application whose executable is abc.exe

This application calls XSLT code to transform XML data to generate html and pdf files

This XSLT code uses jqplots to plot graphs for values specified in the xml file.

The graphs show up beautifully in the generated html and pdf files

**My issue**

abc.exe also has an interface that displays exactly what is in the html/pdf files. It uses a browser object to do that. abc.exe **fails** to display the graphs that show up in the html and pdf files.

**On debugging**

I have this line in XSLT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file://C:/jqplots/jquery.min.js" language="javascript">
```

When the C++ based abc.exe sees this line, it throws the following exception and the graph does not show up:

```
Exception thrown at 0x74E15EF8 in abc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x005BDB9C.
```

The memory locations do not have anything readable. The file mentioned in the 'src' attribute exists and has required permissions. That same XSLT code works to generate html and pdf files

**Question:**

Does the C++ code need a parser to parse the .js file? Is that why it fails? If not, why does the C++ application throw that exception?

Comment: I doubt your statement "This XSLT code uses jqplots to plot graphs", I would rather say that the XSLT code generates a HTML document that contains client-side Javascript to generate a graph, that is, the use of Javascript to generate a graph is not done by the XSLT processor but rather by the browser rendering the HTML document generated by the XSLT code. You would need to ask the author of the C++ program which web browser component it uses to render the XSLT result and whether/how it can handle local, external Javascript files.

Comment: You could try whether a Javascript file loaded over HTTP  (e.g. `src="http://localhost/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"` or e.g. `src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"`) works better or as a last resort you could try to inline the Javascript code in the HTML the XSLT generates, to at least check whether the web browser component has problems handling the used script in general or only the attempt to load it from a file.